# Why is there no flag like MSG_WAITALL for send?

Tags: sockets, send, recv

The flag `MSG_WAITALL` can be used for `recv`, which requests `recv` to block until the full request is satisfied. That means `recv` will not return until as much data as requested (specified by the argument `len`) has been received, unless an error occurs or the connection has been closed.

Why doesn't such a flag apply to `send` too? I think it would be very useful for sending (`send` doesn't return until ALL the bytes the caller wants to send has been handed to TCP send buffer)

Comment: What, to wait until the other side receives it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user207421 is correct, but just to elaborate:

Blocking `send()` (or `write()`) already blocks until all data has been written, it only returns early if no more data can be written, an error occurs, or a signal has been caught, i.e. the same conditions that can cause a blocking `recv()` with `MSG_WAITALL` to return early.

Until recently I also thought a blocking write would behave essentially like a `poll()` for POLLOUT followed by a non-blocking write (but without the race conditions), but it really doesn't.

If you don't believe me, look e.g. at [`unix_stream_sendmsg()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19.17/source/net/unix/af_unix.c#L2099) in the linux kernel (which implements write/send* for AF_UNIX streams): whether or not it will block in its `sock_alloc_send_pskb()` call depends solely on the MSG_DONTWAIT flag (which is [implicitly set](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19.17/source/net/socket.c#L2474) for non-blocking sockets). It does not depend on `sent != 0`, which is what would be needed for non-waitall behaviour.

For comparison, on the read side [`unix_stream_read_generic()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14.21/source/net/unix/af_unix.c#L2319) will avoid blocking if `copied >= target` or `!timeo`, where

- `target` is the `size` argument if MSG_WAITALL, otherwise it's the SO_RCVLOWAT socket option;
- `timeo` is 0 if MSG_DONTWAIT, otherwise it's the SO_RCVTIMEO socket option, and it's updated based on the time spent waiting in `unix_stream_data_wait()`.

The code for TCP is more complicated but [its recvmsg](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19.17/source/net/ipv4/tcp.c#L1213) also uses `target` and `timeo` as described above while [its sendmsg](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19.17/source/net/ipv4/tcp.c#L1213) only uses `timeo` (0 if MSG_DONTWAIT, otherwise SO_SNDTIMEO).

I'm not sure what the reason is for this inconsistency between read and write, but presumably it's just a historical mistake that can't be fixed due to backwards compatibility.

Comment: Very good. The original BSD code is provided in Stevens. Worth a look.

Answer (score 4):

It would be redundant. You can always put the socket into blocking mode, if it isn't already, in which case `send()` blocks until all the data has been transferred into the socket send buffer: and if you’re in non-blocking mode you don’t want to wait for anything, by definition.

Comment: And by *transferred*, you mean *queued to the kernel's send queue*.

Comment: Will a blocking socket really send all the data? `man` says that `send` returns amount of bytes sent which implies something else can happen. Additionally, in this case it's not clear what's the purpose of function `sendall` that languages like Ruby and Python add to their socket modules.

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 The data will be transfered from your buffer to somewhere else. There is no guarantee (and can't be, actually) that the receiving side will actually "receive" your data instead of throwing it away.

Comment: This answer can't be correct. By the same reasoning, MSG_WAITALL isn't need at all - blocking recv() could return when all data requested is read.

Comment: @pfalcon No. `recv()` does not have this behaviour without the MSG_WAITALL flag.

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 Yes,mitmwill transfer all the data. Posix requires it. The return value is for non-blocking mode.

Comment: "No. recv() does not have this behaviour without the MSG_WAITALL flag." - True. send() also doesn't have that behavior without the MSG_WAITALL flag. And as MSG_WAITALL is not available for send(), send() doesn't have that behavior at all. In other words, send() may end with short write at any time, and requires looping on the app side.

Comment: saving a syscall is NOT redundant - the sole reason that the sendfile(2) function EXISTS is to save syscalls.. which are relatively expensive (if you're in userland code, anyway) - and now with SPECTRE/MELTDOWN mitigations, syscalls are more expensive than ever

Comment: @hanshenrik I didn't say anything about 'saving a syscall' being redundant'. I said the *flag* would be redundant, and it is. Don't put words into my mouth.

Comment: @phafcon You are mistaken. Posix requires the behaviour I have described. If it didn't, `send()` *would* have a MSG_WAITALL flag and the question wouldn't have been asked.

Comment: @user207421 if send() had a MSG_WAITALL, you could send a blocking packet on a non-blocking socket with a single syscall, but because it doesn't have that, you have to do 2-3 syscalls: 1: first change it to blocking 2: issue send() 3 (optional): set it back to non-blocking. saving 1-2 syscalls would not be redundant.

Comment: @hanshenrik In other words if `send()` had a MSG_WAITALL you could force a non-blocking socket to block without even realizing it. There is nothing desirable about that. The correct solution for the three-stage scenario you describe is to use `select()` to wait for writeability.

Comment: At least on linux MSG_WAITALL is ignored by `recv()` if combined with MSG_DONTWAIT (which the kernel implicitly adds for sockets with O_NONBLOCK set), so I would expect `send()` to do the same. If you want to mix blocking and non-blocking send/recv you should just keep the socket blocking and use MSG_DONTWAIT when you want a non-blocking send/recv.